# "very low quality" flag got helpful, but (non) answer still there

Tags: support, answers, spam, low-quality-posts

For starters, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092298/640731) is the answer I am talking about.

The question is ancient (2009) and is already answered.

> How to declare an array in Java?

And the answer  (a code only answer)

```
public class{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("secret");
  }
}
```

Either it is a lame attempt to joke, or someone trying to spam.

I first flagged this as "Not an answer" which got disputed. I left it then and waited to see if community takes its own action. I sincerely though someone else flag this answer again and community eventually deletes it.

I checked back in the evening to find the answer still there, so I took a risk and flagged it as "very low quality" which returns as **helpful** without deleting the answer.

Now I don't care whether the answer stays there or not. But what is Stackoverflow's take on answers such as these **which makes no attempt to answer the question?**

As per my observation, these are just noise.  I would like to know the reasoning behind not deleting the answer even after 2 flags. I could keep it in mind when I flag next time.

Comment: That whole question should die a death. In accordance with _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results._ Not least for it being an extremely lazily-asked and mundane question.

Comment: @GrantThomas I know, as per SO policy the question is off topic. But it helped too many newbies once (I was one of them, when I started with android without never setting eye on JAVA).

Comment: The answer is just far too easily discoverable by reading a manual, blog post, or, hell, even a Twitter post; in short, there are so many places where such banality can be explored, SO shouldn't be yet another.

Comment: I can't see any reason to *delete* the question itself. I challenge you to find more more than 20 questions on Stack Overflow whose answers I can't find in a manual or blog post, @Grant.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying that other things present here don't have sufficient coverage elsewhere, that's fallacious. Some things have good exposure and are not suited, some have good exposure and aren't suited. The abundance of info elsewhere is not the basis of my statement.

Comment: @Grant So, you think that you get to decide what is "too easy" to ask on Stack Overflow? 90% of the questions I've answered I thought were "too easy" and covered elsewhere on the web.

Comment: @CodyGray No, it's to do with effort, too, and understanding of the problem, getting out what you put in and all that jazz, as per the off-topic message I reproduced here. I have an opinion, it will either be supported by others or not. It so happens that I think it _should_ be, naturally; and it's also obvious that the question wouldn't last minutes today - without some phenomenon allowing the votes to escape velocity, so to speak.

Comment: Ok it seems the answer got deleted. I wonder why it took so much time.

Comment: It got deleted because you posted a link to it on Meta. Three 20k+ users voted to delete it: AakashM, myself, and Daniel Fischer. Welcome to Meta, where we eat bad content for breakfast.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: Regarding the question and usefulness, don't get me wrong but if you need to look up how to declare an array in a language you'll now work with...there's something wrong with you not even reading up on the basics (documentation) of that language. Also it's called Java, not JAVA.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby [This](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=declare+an+array+in+java) is what I find when I look up at google. And when I see the accepted answer on that question, I can tell there is not much difference in Array declaration compared with other languages that I have worked with. I know it is good to learn a language in systematic way, but it is not alway possible when you feel client/requirement/deadline on your throat.

Comment: Btw The question is closed/protected. What good can we expect from deleting that? There are thousands of off topic questions in stackoverflow, which are closed/not deleted, and this question comes into discussion only because of its popularity and usefulness.